# layout - How to create a personnalized header's layout?

Tags: macros, fancyhdr, layout

I'm writing a thesis and I wanted to personalized my headers like on this picture:
[image]

In a first time (1):

- On even pages, I'd like to have on left, the page number, and on the
  right, the chapter name.
- On odd pages, I'd like to have on left, the
  current section and the current subsection, and on the right, the
  page number.

Here is my code for the headers configuration:

```latex
% % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % 
% HEADERS AND FOOTERS
% = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = 
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.05}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\let\Sectionmark\sectionmark
\def\sectionmark#1{\def\Sectionname{#1}\Sectionmark{#1}}
\let\Subsectionmark\subsectionmark
\def\subsectionmark#1{\def\Subsectionname{#1}\Subsectionmark{#1}}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter. #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ \ #1}{}}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}

% page pair
\fancyhead[LE]{\textbf{\thepage}\hspace{3pt}{\color{MyGrey}\greytriangleright}\hspace{3pt} \\{}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\MakeUppercase{\leftmark} \\{}}

%page impair
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark \\{} \thesubsection\ \Subsectionname}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\hspace{3pt}{\color{MyGrey}\greytriangleleft}\hspace{3pt}\textbf{\thepage} \\{}}

\setlength{\headheight}{45pt}

\let\headruleORIG\headrule
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\color{black} \headruleORIG}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \fancyhead{}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\bfseries\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\makeatletter
\def\@textbottom{\vskip \z@ \@plus 1pt}
\let\@texttop\relax
\makeatother

% % Clear Header Style on the Last Empty Odd pages
\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else%
\hbox{}%
\thispagestyle{empty}% % Empty header styles
\newpage%
\if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother
```

In a second time (2), how can I create an area on the extern marge of pages to have a notation of the current chapter?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can do that either with package `fancyhdr` or with `titleps`, which comes with `titlesec`.

Comment: I'm using `fancyhdr` but it seems that it does not work... And for the chapter marks ?

Comment: Did you read in detail the documentation. Of course, there also may be a problem with your document class, if it is not one of the standard classes. I suggest you post a minimal (yet complete) code reproducing your difficulties;

Comment: My document code is a bit long, but the doc class is book.

Comment: Do you want your header flush with the top of the paper?  You can do that with geometry {top=0pt}.  Theoretically you can overlap the side margins with fancyhdr, but it would be easier to use `\AddToHook{shipout/background}{...}` directly.